# ¿Porqué usar "document.querySelector()" y no "querySelector()"?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo están? Recién estoy que aprendiendo Java Script y me encontrado con esta duda. Me podrían ayudar por favor.

Este es parte de mi código.
Por ejemplo, lo que quiero es llamar a esa etiqueta: `<input type="text">`

```
<body>
   <input type="text">
   <button>Verificar si acertó.</button>
</body>
<script>
   var secreto = 5; 
   var input = document.querySelector("input"); /* Aquí quisiera saber porque tengo que usar el document y no solo el */ `.querySelector` /* para llamar a la etiqueta mencionada en la parte superior. */ 
<script>
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De hecho puedes usar el metodo `querySelector` en la mayorias de los nodos del DOM, pero al ser un metodo estas obligado a acceder primero al objeto que contiene esta funcion que en este caso es `document` y luego al metodo. Para entender esto te recomiendo que aprendas un poco de programacion orientada a objetos.

Y como recomendación, es mejor que utilices el metodo `document.getElementById` ya que es mucho mas rápido que `document.querySelector`.

Answer (score 0):

Es correcto como te dijeron arriba. Si quieres acceder a él, es más recomendable usar un ID o una clase. Por ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" class="campo1">
```

Y acceder a él mediante:

```
document.querySelector(".campo1");
```

También es recomendable usar `Let` cuando pienses modificarlas (pero no pueden re-declararse) algo y `const` no quieras modificarlas (tampoco pueden re-declararse).

Por ejemplo, si quisieras cambiar el tipo de input, podrías hacerlo así:

```js
const campo = document.querySelector(".campo1");
//Usamos setAttribute para modificarlo
campo.setAttribute("type", "range");
```

```html
<input type="text" class="campo1">
```